# Double (overlapped) TODO note in margin

Tags: todonotes

My TODO notes are appearing in double when I use `author=` and `size=\tiny` options. I first saw this in LyX, where with `fancyline` it appeared to be drawing two overlapping lines. But it turns out I'm seeing something unusual in TeXstudio (MikTeX, Windows 10), too.

Screenshot of the PDF viewer in TeXstudio:

[image]

Here's the same, but zoomed in to the part showing what appears to be a note (without the author) below a note with an author and comment:

[image]

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
This is \todo[size=\tiny,author=Me]{Here's a long comment that wraps around in the margin}a
test
\end{document}
```

Is this a bug in package `todonotes`?

Comment: If you check the Log of your editor, you will be hinted at the problem. I don't know how to resolve it but it's a start. The error is: `Undefined control sequence. \ttl@finishall`

Comment: @KhalidHussain no errors appear in my log. I see only one warning, `LaTeX Warning: Marginpar on page 1 moved.`

Comment: Checking the `todonotes` manual, the same thing seems to occur. I'm on TeX Live and on page 7 of the PDF, the example for the`author` option suffers from the same problem you're seeing.

Comment: @KhalidHussain Indeed. It's less obvious because the text does not wrap and the size of the font doesn't leave space between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it seems to be a bug, caused by the usage of `\tiny`.

Please see the following MWE (`blindtext` is only used to have dummy text available):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
This is\todo[size=\tiny,author=Me]{Here's a long comment that wraps 
  around in the margin}\ 
 a test. 
\blindtext
This is \todo[author=Me]{Here's a long comment that wraps 
  around in the margin} 
 a test. 
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

As you can see with the usual font size there is no error in the output:

[image]

Comment: The problem is still there, it's just hidden.

Comment: It's been patched. See https://github.com/henrikmidtiby/todonotes/pull/9